# Overview of using Authorization Code grant type to authenticate a user in django

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, oauth-2.0

I have a django app that Im using drf and ReactJS for my frontend and token authentication. I've been messing around with various packages in Django so that I can implement Social Authentication. I was using implicit authorization but am wanting to switch to an Authorization Code Grant Type. I have been able to make the request, redirect to a callback url on my server where I am able to make a post request to get the user data, refresh token and access token. This is where I have gotten a little stuck because Im not sure how to return those tokens to the frontend. After I authenticate I need to be able to redirect to a "success" page but dont know how to inlcude the access token in that redirect. I know I could use django sessions and just store the tokens there and use that for my authentication but I was hoping to use Token authentication where the user includes their access token to access secure data.

I was able to come up with two "working" solutions.

**With Set-Cookie**

```
response = HttpResponseRedirect("/login-success")
response.set_cookie("access_token", "<access_token>")

return HttpResponseRedirect
```

**Appending <access_token>**

```
return HttpResponseRedirect("/login-success#<access_token>") # parse token when page is reached
```

I feel like these are not the "correct" way of doing this but I dont know where to go from here.

```
import requests

from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.shortcuts import redirect

class TwitchLogin(ApiView):

    def _generate_token(self, request):
        code = request.GET.get('code', None)
        if code is not None:
            token_params = {
                'client_id': TWITCH_CLIENT_ID,
                'client_secret': TWITCH_CLIENT_SECRET,
                'code': code,
                'redirect_uri': TWITCH_REDIRECT_URI,
                'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
            }
            response = requests.post(TWITCH_TOKEN_URL, params=token_params)
            if response.ok:
                credentials = response.json()
                return {
                    credentials['refresh_token'],
                    credentials['access_token']
                }
        return None

    def _get_token(self, request):
        try:
            return request.session['access_token']
        except KeyError:
            return self._generate_token(request)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect("/login/success")
        token = self._get_token(request)
        if token is not None:
            user = authenticate(request, token=token)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect("/login/success")
        
    return redirect("/login/failed")
```

This is my current view and I just need a better way of including the token.

Answer (score 0):

With the `django-rest-framework-simplejwt` package, you can do what you want much easier.
You can install this package using the following command.

```
pip install djangorestframework-simplejwt
```

In settings.py, you can configure which authentication you'll use.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'rest_framework_simplejwt',
    ...
]

...

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        ...
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    )
    ...
}
```

You can create tokens manually like the following.

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken

def get_tokens_for_user(user):
    refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)

    return {
        'refresh': str(refresh),
        'access': str(refresh.access_token),
    }
```

Using this function, you can send your tokens in any API view.

```
return Response(get_tokens_for_user(user), status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: Yeah this makes sense but how I  need to be able to incorporate Twitch’s auth because the code they redirect my users with provides my app with necessary user dat associated with that data. And I get stuck on my backend because I can’t return a render because I’m using react. I have to redirect back to front end